# How to define varchar and enum in TypeORM?

Tags: postgresql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have database structure need to declare the variable into `varchar`, `int`, and `enum` using TypeORM in TypeScript. But in TypeScript doesn't have data type varchar and int. How do I declare it?

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtYGu.png)

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    account_id: varchar;

    @Column()
    email: varchar;

    @Column()
    phone_number: varchar;

    @Column()
    address: varchar;

    @Column()
    status: enum;

    @Column()
    current_id: varchar;
}
```

Comment: You can use `string` and `number` for varchar and int. Also check the official typescript docs for all available  types.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your respond

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Column types in the database are inferred from the property types you used, e.g. number will be converted into integer, string into varchar, boolean into bool, etc. But you can use any column type your database supports by implicitly specifying a column type into the @Column decorator.

```
import {Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Photo {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({
        length: 100
    })
    name: string;

    @Column("text")
    description: string;

    @Column()
    filename: string;

    @Column("double")
    views: number;

    @Column()
    isPublished: boolean;
}
```

Since you are already using typeorm you can use types defined here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/entities.md#column-types

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for your help

Comment: @firdaus Could you please approve the answer if it resolves your query.